# Rails:Is it possible to use active_scoffold gem in rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I installed that gem,when I run

```
rails g active_scaffold:install
```

It says

> Running via Spring preloader in process 6001
>
> Could not find generator 'scoffold'. Maybe you meant 'scaffold', 'css:scaffold' or 'erb:scaffold'
>
> Run `rails generate --help` for more options.

**gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'active_scaffold', github: 'activescaffold/active_scaffold', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: In the [docs](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold) it says that _"Rails >= 4.0.5 is supported, ruby >= 2.0 supported"_ so it should work. Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: I ran the bundle when i run the command 'rails g active_scaffold User name:string' it says that defined error

Comment: Did you run `bundle exec rake db:create` before `rails g active_scaffold User name:string`?

Comment: I am run that command still its says that error

Comment: I got a solution, i ran their defined commands in another procedure

Comment: happy for ur help Vucko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

I changed the steps to install the gem, that steps are

1.Insert the gem in gem file, **gem 'active_scaffold'** and run **bundle install**.

2.Run the command **"rails g active_scaffold User name:string"**.

3.In gemfile change **gem 'active_scaffold' to "gem 'active_scaffold', github: 'activescaffold/active_scaffold', branch: 'master'** " and install the bundle once again.

4.Create a DB by **"bundle exec rake db:create"**.

5.Run **"rails g active_scaffold:install"**.

6.Finally migrate it **"rake db:migrate"**